# The number of files you're expecting will be uploaded. Is this sentence correct?

Tags: sentence-construction

Which is the (grammatically) correct sentence structure?

1. What is the number of files you're expecting to be/get uploaded?
2. What is the number of files you're expecting will be/get uploaded?

or something else...?

Comment: What is the number of files you expect to be/get uploaded?....................................
What will be the number of files you expect to be/get uploaded?

Comment: **How many** files are you expecting **to be** uploaded?